# Printing a string from a resource file outside of an asp control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a resource file in the App_GlobalResources folder and i would like to print some of the string in things like the alt text of images and the title of a href links. I know this can be done using asp.net controls for asp:Image and asp:Hyperlink then print the striong with the <%$ but what I would like to do is use the normal HTML a href and img tags and then print the resource string in that. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , using

```
 <img src="..." runat="server" id="myUniqueID" />
```

can be accessed in code-behind just like `<asp:Image />` would be

most HTML elements with runat attribute and a unique id can be accessed from the viewstate just like an asp: element would be

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of just adding the runat command I just tested it and that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Media Selectors to distinguish between screen CSS and print CSS.

An example for hyperlinks is given in [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/). This may not work for all browsers, though.